# ActiveRecord is not including a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a query like this:

```
PrimaryModel.includes(:associated_models)
  .where(foo: true)
  .where('associated_models.bar >= 0')
```

Typically, this would prompt ActiveRecord to join in associated_models, but instead I get this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: 
>   missing FROM-clause entry for table "associated_models"

However, a query like this will properly join the tables:

```
PrimaryModel.includes(:associated_models)
  .where(foo: true)
  .where(associated_models: { baz: true })
```

Also, and perhaps most telling, this works:

```
PrimaryModel.includes(:associated_models)
  .where(foo: true)
  .where(associated_models: { baz: true })
  .where('associated_models.bar >= 0')
```

In this last one, 'associated_models' gets joined by `.where(associated_models: { baz: true })`, allowing `.where('associated_models.bar >= 0')` to work properly. Anyone else experience this? Figure out a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you will be using the association name in a query as you tried, you have to say it explicitly:

```
PrimaryModel.includes(:associated_models)
  .where(foo: true)
  .where('associated_models.bar >= 0')
  .references(:associated_models) # should be actual table name.
```

Read [conditions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) part from doco.

But as you saw, the explicit mention is not needed when you will write it like a `Hash` syntax - `.where(associated_models: { baz: true })`.